# Android Room Date

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I am trying to run a query that returns records grouped by date. However, I am battling with the `Date` object. I have the following model to accept the data from the Room query:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class TotalAssessmentsPerDay {

    private int total;
    private Date date;

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

And here is my query:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, DATE(timestamp) AS date FROM SUBJECTIVEASSESSMENT WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)")
    List<TotalAssessmentsPerDay> getTotalAssessmentsPerDay();
```

I get results so far but for some reason the `date` parameter returns null. I do not know how exactly to approach this. What object type does the `DATE(timestamp)` command return? All I get is the value for `total` but `date` remains null. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**"

I save my timestamp as `String` in this format "dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm". Here is my `TypeConverter`:

```
public class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    public static Date fromTimestamp(Long value) {
        return value == null ? null : new Date(value);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long dateToTimestamp(Date date) {
        return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: "What object type does the DATE(timestamp) command return?" -- probably `String`. "What am I doing wrong?" -- I think you need a `@TypeConverter` for `Date`. I am surprised that the Room compiler isn't complaining, though.

Comment: MIght not be the solution to your problem, but did you consider using the Instant class? This class is generally more accepted when working with any DAO in Java.

Comment: i personally save date as a long (if you want to save the timestamp)

Comment: @CommonsWare I made an edit to my question. I added the converter

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if you can directly convert a timestamp as a Date object, try using a `DateFormat` object to parse the string as a date object. Because if it sorts correctly, the date is present but it means it cannot be parsed to a Date object directly.